# Limit for coins in plants versus zombies 2

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

Is there a limit for the amount of coins you can keep? What happens if you gain more than 99,999 ?

Comment: I'm guessing it overflows the box, nothing special.

Comment: Well the options are either overflow, or it caps (you can still collect them, but you never actually get more than the cap). Eg. If I have 99,999; and I collect 100 more, then by something worth 1000, it'd drop to 98,999. Don't know which it is for PVZ2 though\

Answer (score 2):

6 digits can fit in the black area. It looks like the font size gets smaller to compensate for the additional digit.

[image]

I don't think there is a reasonable limit for coins, given that you're able to purchase 450,000 in the largest bundle.

Answer (score -1):

> The player cannot have more than $999,990 on most versions; once that amount is reached, all money collected won't affect their total.

**EDIT:**

> On the iOS and Android versions it is possible to earn up to $9,000,000!

[see unofficial wiki](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Money)

Comment: You can get more than 1 million coins. I have more than 1 million :P

Comment: "Most versions" does not include PvZ2.

Comment: @Ciacciu you are probably a IOS or android user. i edited my answer

Comment: @Gigazelle who says this? sources?

Comment: Indeed, IOS user. Too bad I later forgot to add the screenshot >.<